# equivalent function for this graph

Tags: functions

$ \forall x\in (0,n] $

$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ $\in$ (0, 1]} \\
x,  & \text{if $x$ $\in$ (1, 3]} \\
3,  & \text{if $x$ $\in$ (3, n]} \\
\end{cases}
$

[image]

How can I write this function in a simplified format(in a single line)?

Which is the function that generates the above chart?

Comment: May I ask what is the point of insisting on writing a function on one line?

Comment: $2+\tanh(x-2)$ : A [smooth version](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202%2btanh%28x-2%29)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni too smooth :)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I like it! TY, but why didn't you post your solution as answer, not comment

Comment: Thanks to both (I made this an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that $n > 3$
$$
f(x) = 1+(x-1)\cdot \theta(x)\cdot\theta(3-x) + 2\theta(x-3)
$$

[image]

Where
$$\theta(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
0, & x < 0 \\
1, & x \ge 0
\end{array} \right.
$$ is so called [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

Comment: ty, but who si $ \theta $

Comment: @doledoug Just in case, if you want to make sure [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%281+%2B+%28x+-+1%29+HeavisideTheta[x+-+1]*HeavisideTheta[3+-+x]+%2B++++2+HeavisideTheta[x+-+3])

Comment: always $ x> 0$ and why did you mention $n>3$ condition?

Comment: 1) $x-3$ and $3-x$ are not always > 0; 2) If $n < 3$ your conditions don't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=\chi_{(0,1]}+x\chi_{(1,3]}+3\chi_{(3,n]}$, where 
$
\chi_A(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ $\in$ A} \\
0,  & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$
for every subset $A$ of $[0,n]$

Answer (score 1):

A [smooth version](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202%2btanh%28x-2%29) :

$$2+\tanh(x-2)$$

[image]

A 'less smooth' version is : 
$$2+\sqrt [3]{\tanh\left((x-2)^3\right)}$$

[image: with cube root]

(using [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20cuberoot%5Btanh%5B%28x-2%29%5E3%5D%5D%2b2))

For other alternatives see ['sigmoid function'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) and this picture :

[image: picture].